# Require a code for login page for admin

Tags: ios

I Want to Create an app for iOS Device which have only admin login and user register with names and email-id do not need their password  but user does not need to login here.Only the admin can login and can view the user information only.
MY Question is:"For admin login page (UserName and Password)have match from the web Server which is using same as their Website username and password"?

am beginner

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same web server you could have a separate route for login through the app say : '/login/admin'. This route has to be on the same web service which the web site uses.

You can then use the same validation that is used for the website but now you would also need to check that along with a valid username and password the user type has to be admin or any other flag that you system uses to distinguish users from admins.